# Memory hole remap bios killswitch?

Tags: bios

Can I disable memory hole remapping option/killswitch in my BIOS? I suspect it to cause random freezes.

Comment: I have some idea but am not entirely sure what you mean by "memory hole remap killswitch".  Can you please be more specific as to what you're asking here?

Comment: I've a 64-bit os and 8 gb-ram is this information enough? I also mean killswitch = option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can disable memory hole remapping, but you'll [lose the ability to use approximately 1GB of your RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_hole) by doing so.

For a permanent solution, you should contact your motherboard manufacturer for an updated BIOS or replacement hardware to resolve the problem.